# Hangman game with a bug in my choice method

Tags: ruby

Excuse my global variables, this is a Hangman project I am working on. Everything is working as it should except for one part of this method.

```
def choice(n)
  $random_word2.each_with_index do |i,index|
    if i == n
      $cipher[index] = i 
    end 
  end 
    if n == $random_word
      puts "You win"
    end
    if $random_word2.include?(n) == false
      $counter -= 1
      display
      puts "incorrect guess"
    end
  puts $cipher.join 
end
```

Specifically these lines. As it is the program will print out $random_word so you will know what it is since it is random. If you type the whole word it should print "You win!" but instead it skips to the last "if" and accepts it as a incorrect guess. I tried different variables and it works, so that leads me to believe that the $random_word variable changes to a different random word at some point? I am lost, it prints the word, I type in the exact same thing and somehow it's not == .

```
if n == $random_word
  puts "You win"
```

this is the whole program.

```
 load 'display.rb'

class Hangman
  attr_accessor :name
  @name = name

  def initialize
    puts "What is your name?"
    @name = gets.chomp
    puts "
################################################
                   HANGMAN
################################################

               _________
              |        
              |       |
              |       O
              |      /|\\
              |       |
              |      / \\
              |
              -----------------
Welcome #{@name} to Hangman. The computer will generate
a 5-12 letter random word. You will try to guess
that word one letter at a time. Try to solve the
puzzle before time runs out! 


"
  Gameplay.new
  end
end

class Gameplay
  def initialize
    $array = []
    File.foreach('5text.txt') do |x| $array << x if (x.chomp.length >= 5 and x.chomp.length <= 12) end
    $random_word = $array.sample
    $random_word2 = $random_word.split(//)
    puts $random_word2.join
    $cipher = $random_word.gsub(/[a-z]/, '*').split(//)
    puts $cipher.join

  def choice(n)
    $random_word2.each_with_index do |i,index|
      if i == n
        $cipher[index] = i 
      end 
    end 
      if n == $random_word2.join.to_s
        puts "You win"
      end
      if $random_word2.include?(n) == false
        $counter -= 1
        display
        puts "incorrect guess"
      end
      if $counter == 0
        puts "you lose!!!!!!"
        puts "would you like to start another game? Y/N"
        new_game = gets.chomp
        if new_game == "Y"
          Hangman.new
        end
      end 
        puts $cipher.join 
end


$counter = 5
while $counter > 0
choice(gets.chomp)
    end
  end
end
Hangman.new
```

Comment: Please indent your classes. Also, don't use global `$` variables within a class, use instance `@`  variables or local variables. And be careful with naming: `n` sounds like a number, `$random_word2` would be better named `@letters` because it's an array of letters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When you said indent my classes, do you mean put two spaces before "class Hangman"? I haven't really figured out the indentation standard yet.

Comment: Everything inside your class should be indented two spaces. Same with any do/end block. You have some problems with `end` placement so this will shine some light on it. Go ahead and [edit] your question with better indenting, it will be easier to follow.

Comment: You can check length of n and $random_word.

Comment: Have you looked carefully at the contents of `$array`? I believe the words contain newlines because you didn't `chomp` them before storing them.

Comment: Edited my indentation, think I got it right? I'll take a look now at the contents of $array.

Comment: When you have it working, stop by [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you're interesting in improving the code!

Comment: The game itself works but the next part of the assignment is to serialize so that I can save and load the game at any time. Starting that now, I'll be sure to stop by the code review when I finish, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
File.foreach('5text.txt') do |x|
  chomped = x.chomp
  $array << chomped if (chomped.length >= 5 and chomped.length <= 12)
end
```

Because the words have a `\n` not chomped in your origin program.